# Is "et que la chance soit au rendez-vous" to be taken literally or is it an expression?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I think it's similar to "et que le bonheur soit au rendez-vous", I have issues understanding both statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, *rendez-vous* is not to be taken literally (appointment) but means the place or the period of time where some event already being referred to will take place in the future.

It is similar to the English:

> and may the luck be (there) with you/them.